# using enigma on mcrypt

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

So my goal is to demonstrate an online version of the enigma machine. I'm using PHP to do this and using mcrypt as it seems to be the only way to use the enigma algorithm without writing it out myself. 
Trouble is there is no information out there currently on how to set up mcrypt's enigma. 
I am also using stream as nothing else seems to work before anyone asks.
I really would be greatful for any help regarding this.

This is my current setup.

```
$td = mcrypt_module_open('enigma', '', 'stream', '');
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
$ks = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td);
$key = substr(md5('very secret key'), 0, $ks);
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, 'This is very important data');
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $encrypted);
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
mcrypt_module_close($td);
echo trim($decrypted) . "\n";
```

How do I get it encrypt in the enigma way then display it in ciphertext aswell as the ordinary text?

Answer (score 0):

When running you're code I'm getting this warning:

```
Warning: mcrypt_create_iv(): Cannot create an IV with a size of less than 1 or greater than 2147483647
```

The error occurs because

```
mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td)
```

gives an value of '0':

```
$ivSize = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);
echo "ivSize: " . $ivSize;
ivSize: 0
```

The solution is to use a blank IV:

```
$iv = "";
```

and everything works like expected:

```
echo trim($decrypted) . "\n";
This is very important data
```